# Reply to selected Outlook emails using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

Using Excel VBA, I want to reply to emails which I selected/highlighted inside the Outlook application.

There are different email messages and subject lines based on the order which I selected the email messages.

There are replies to the wrong email. It should reply to those which I highlighted in Outlook.

For example when I selected three emails there are instances that two replied correctly but the other one replied to an email which I did not highlight.

```vb
Sub SendEmail()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object  
    i = 1

    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 4))  
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i)   
        Dim OutlookConversation As Object
        Set OutlookConversation = OutlookMail.GetConversation  
        Dim OutlookTable As Object
        Set OutlookTable = OutlookConversation.GetTable 
        Dim OutlookAr As Variant
        OutlookAr = OutlookTable.GetArray(OutlookTable.GetRowCount)
        Dim OutlookReplyToThisMail As Object
        Set OutlookReplyToThisMail = OutlookMail.Session.GetItemFromID(OutlookAr(UBound(OutlookAr), 0))
        With OutlookReplyToThisMail.ReplyAll
            .Subject = Sheet1.Cells(1 + i, 15) & "_" & .Subject
            .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:13'>" & _
            Sheet1.Cells(34, 2 + i) & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
            Sheet1.Cells(35, 2 + i) & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
            Sheet1.Cells(36, 2 + i) & Signature & .HTMLBody
            .Display     
        End With 

        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What is on cells `Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 4))`?

Comment: Also, would you not want to reply to the selected message, rather than the one selected by the user? When you say "replying to the wrong email", what is the wrong email and what would be the right email?

Comment: There are instances that when i ran the code, it replied the email which i did not selected/highlighted. It should only reply the email which i selected in outlook

Answer (score 1):

First of all, creating a new Outlook `Application` instance in the loop is not actually a good idea:

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 4))  
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Instead, consider moving the creation line above before the loop:

```
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 4))
```

In the code you are iterating over Excel cells and get corresponding selected items in Outlook.

> it should only reply those which i highlighted in outlook email.

If you need to iterate over all selected items in Outlook you need to not rely on the Excel's data and have got a separate loop based on the number of selected items. For example:

```
 Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer  
 Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection 
 Set myOlExp = OutlookApplication.ActiveExplorer  
 Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection  
 For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count  
   If myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then  
     ' For mail item, use the SenderName property. 
     Set oMail = myOlSel.Item(x)  
     Debug.Print oMail.SenderName 
   End If
 Next
```